# Dry aging at home - is it really possible?

Tags: chemistry, dry-aging

I am thinking to test the process of dry aging at home. I have some questions:

What exactly are the processes a piece of meat experiences, in this case, beef, from the time it is slaughtered to the time its cuts show up in the meat counter in your local market.

How do these processes deviate from the beef that is labeled as 'dry-aged' in the meat counter.

Dry-aging is supposed to achieve two things:
1) Evaporate moisture and concentrate flavor
2) Enzymes break protein into glutamic acids (umami components)

I have noticed that there is plenty of debate about the time involved required to properly dry-age. Is there any research about the time involved for the chemical reactions related to the 2nd part?

Comment: I've nominated this for re-opening because it is not the same as the linked "hanging at home" question...also, I don't think the linked "hanging at home" question is answered effectively either.